# TypeError: command_prefix must be plain string, iterable of strings, or callable returning either of these, not NoneType

Tags: python, sqlite, discord, discord.py

Even though I am weak in sql, I don't think the problem is from sql
With the same situation, it worked correctly 1 time, but it stopped working
I have no idea, please help
This problem really bothers me

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mahdiyar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1199, in get_prefix      
    ret = list(ret)  # type: ignore
          ^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mahdiyar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 409, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Mahdiyar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1394, in on_message      
    await self.process_commands(message)
  File "C:\Users\Mahdiyar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1389, in process_commands    ctx = await self.get_context(message)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Mahdiyar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1288, in get_context     
    prefix = await self.get_prefix(origin)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Mahdiyar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1206, in get_prefix      
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: command_prefix must be plain string, iterable of strings, or callable returning either of these, not NoneType
```

code:

```
async def get_prefix(client, message):
    async with aiosqlite.connect("sqlite2023.db") as db:
        async with db.cursor() as cursor:
            await cursor.execute('SELECT prefix FROM prefix WHERE guild = ?' , (message.guild.id,))
            data = await cursor.fetchone()
            if data:
                return data
            else:
                try:
                    await cursor.execute('INSERT INTO prefix (prefix, guild) VALUES (? , ?)', ('!', message.guild.id,))
                    await cursor.execute('SELECT prefix FROM prefix WHERE guild = ?' , (message.guild.id,))
                    data = await cursor.fetchone()
                    if data:
                        cursor.execute('UPDATE prefix SET prefix = ? WHERE guild = ? ' , ('!',message.guild.id,))
                except Exception:
                    return '!'

@client.event #Client Statusa
async def on_ready():
    forever_print.start()
    asyncio.create_task(rich_persence())
    print("Client is online!")
    async with aiosqlite.connect("sqlite2023.db") as db:
        async with db.cursor() as cursor:
            await cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS prefix (prefix TEXT ,guild ID)')
        await db.commit()
```

Comment: Can you show how you're creating your `commands.Bot` instance?

Comment: ```intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.message_content = True 
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=getprefix , intents=intents)```

@stijndcl

Answer (score 0):

The `try` block in that function doesn't return anything, so if it doesn't raise an exception then it returns `None` instead of a prefix.

Comment: Can you show me the solution in a code?

Comment: No, I won't do it for you. It's also quite basic Python, just return something in the `try` block..

Comment: Ah-huh @stijndcl

Comment: ..............?